# Opencv on android studio failing update

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I'm trying to install opencv on android studio but i get this error,when i try to update build.gradle:

Cause:failed to find target with hash string 'android-14'

But in the sdk manager there is no api level 14 to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you imported the Android Program from the examples provided by OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html).

(*Note* Eclipse is deprecated but as long as you import the Eclipse project into Android Studio it will still be there.*)

I assumed you are using OpenCV 3.0.

After you import, you will see "openCVLibrary310" folder. Change the "compileSDKVersion 14" to "compileSDKVersion [your version]" and rebuild the gradle!

Good luck!